# Modules requiring each other cause error "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have two different modules that need to require each other. I understand it creates an infinite loop and can't work. Is there a way to circumvent it?

Comment: As noted in an answer below, circular `require`s are fully legal in Node.js. Could you please edit your answer to include a small, complete example that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Node.js allows circular require (see [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)). So most likely the infinite loop that is causing the error is a recursive function call (A calls B calls A ...) that never ends. Make sure that all functions complete finitely.

Answer (score 1):

You can change one module to a proxy.

It's likely one of the modules doesn't immediately need the other one. If you pass in a proxy you can use it to get the dependency at a later time (like just-in-time).